# Destination Register = Source Register, [ldr r0, r0]

Tags: assembly, arm

I often see in my ARM assembler code (ARMv7) such an expression:

```
ldr r3, [r3, #0]
```

It means r3 = r3 + 0, doesn't it? But what's the purpose?

Comment: Commonly this is a list traversal code.  So if you have `struct node { struct node *next; int data; };` and you use `struct node p = p->next;`, then you this exact assembler.  I guess you are trying to understand some compiled code.

Answer (score 7):

No, it doesn't.

It means "load r3 with the data from memory (this is a *load*, after all) at address `r3 + 0`".

An instruction to move the value of `r3` to `r3`, i.e. not involving memory, would be a `mov`.

Answer (score 1):

No! "ldr rd,[rn, #offset]" Loads rd from a word "offset" bytes above the address in rn.
"rd = rn + 0" would like add rd,rn,#0